# How to properly run Eclemma coverage with Java

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco, eclemma

We use non-java tests. Each one of them executes our tool which is written in Java.
I'm trying to use Eclemma for creating the coverage report of the tests. 
Lets start with one test. We compile the code with `build.xml`. I would like somehow to create a coverage report for each test and then to merge them into one main report.
I found out that [Jacoco has CMD interface](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html) I could use in order to merge those reports. But I don't understand how do I run the tool with coverage package?

1. Which coverage package should I use? Is it Eclemma or Jacoco?
2. How do I run the tool with the coverage package? Should I add it into the build.xml file? Should I add it to the command line?

I'm a bit confused about the whole idea of coverage in Java. In dynamic langues such as Python and Perl, I just execute the code with the coverage module, which creates the coverage report.

The command we use to execute out tool:

```
gandu -vm /usr/pkgs/java/1.6.0.25-64/bin/java -configuration /.ganduData -data /.ganduData -configuration /ganduInternalConfig --session_id 1582722179
```

Should I add some options?

The build in `build.xml`:

```
<target name="pde-build" depends="clean, init">
    <java classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-application" />
        <arg value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner" />
        <arg value="-buildfile" />
        <arg value="${eclipseLocation}/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_${pdeBuildPluginVersion}/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml" />
        <arg value="-Dtimestamp=${timestamp}" />
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${eclipseLocation}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_${equinoxLauncherPluginVersion}.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Should I add the following command?

```
<arg value="-autVMArgs" />      
<arg value="-Xmx800m;-XX:MaxPermSize=600M;-javaagent:${jacoco-agent-path}=destfile=${jacoco-report},append=true"/>
```

**Update:** Thanks to the two answer I have managed to create the report using the CLI. But it looks like it shows (almost) zero coverage. It shows red (uncovered) on printed lines that I see that have been executed (they were printed to the stdout).

The project contains a lot of packages but for first try I'm trying to create coverage report for a specific package. I ran:

```
gandu -vm /usr/pkgs/java/1.6.0.25-64/bin/java -configuration /.ganduData -data /.ganduData --session_id 1583967465 -vmargs -Xmx256m -Xms128m -javaagent:/jacoco_coverage/jacoco-0.8.5/lib/jacocoagent.jar
```

and then I ran:

```
/usr/pkgs/java/1.6.0.16-64/bin/java -jar /jacoco_coverage/jacoco-0.8.5/lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles /gandu_repo/com.core.gandu/bin/ --html temp_dir --sourcefiles /gandu_repo/com.core.gandu/src/
```

The output:

```
[WARN] Some classes do not match with execution data.
[WARN] For report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime.
[WARN] Execution data for class <PATH> does not match.
[INFO] Analyzing 8 classes.
```

I have trouble understanding how `classfiles` and `sourcefiles`. The file that I'm trying to get coverage on is `Application`. In the `bin` I have in some inner folder `Application.class` and in `src` I have in some inner folder `Application.java`. I even tried to add full path for the those files in `classfiles` and `sourcefiles` but still don't have coverage (all red). What could be the problem?
The structure of the tool:
The root contains alot of packages and each one has folder `bin` and `src`. Each `src` contains folders recursively with Java files. The `bin` has the same structure for `class` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As I know, the only place to add java agent is in the configuration of the unit tests.

**Agent should be added to the JVM that executes application under test.** Your confusion probably comes from the fact that usually unit tests are executed in the same JVM as code under test.

From your description unclear how JVM with the application is started.

However consider following `src/Main.java` as an example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input;
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
      input = reader.readLine();
    }
    if ("hello".equals(input)) {
      System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
  }

}
```

after compilation

```
javac -d classes src/Main.java
```

This application can be executed in JVM with [JaCoCo Java Agent](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) taken from [JaCoCo zip distribution](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/) as following

```
java -javaagent:jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar -cp classes Main
```

Then tests are executed - e.g. in this case manual input of "hello".

After graceful termination of JVM, you'll get `jacoco.exec` file.

By passing this `jacoco.exec`, source and class files to the [JaCoCo Command Line Interface](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html) you can create HTML report:

```
java -jar jacoco/lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles classes --sourcefiles src --html report
```

[image: report]

> Which coverage package should I use? Is it Eclemma or Jacoco?

EclEmma is a plugin for Eclipse IDE based on JaCoCo.

If for testing you execute your application from Eclipse IDE then you can start it with JaCoCo using EclEmma. Here is the same example executed in Eclipse IDE:

[image: EclEmma]

However this is not suitable for other scenarios such as Ant builds.

> How do I run the tool with the coverage package? Should I add it into the build.xml file? Should I add it to the command line?

This depends on how you execute your application - if for tests your application is executed by Ant, then you can use [JaCoCo Ant Tasks](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) for configuration of agent and generation of report. As an example here is `build.xml` for Ant that produces the same report for `src/Example.java` as the above commands:

```
<project xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" name="Example Ant Build with JaCoCo" default="rebuild">

  <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar"/>
  </taskdef>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="classes"/>
    <delete dir="report"/>
    <delete file="jacoco.exec"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="classes" debug="true" includeantruntime="false"/>
  </target>

  <target name="run" depends="compile">
    <jacoco:agent property="jacocoAgent" />

    <java classname="Main" fork="true">
      <classpath path="classes"/>
      <jvmarg value="${jacocoAgent}"/>
    </java>
  </target>

  <target name="report" depends="run">
    <jacoco:report>
      <executiondata>
        <file file="jacoco.exec"/>
      </executiondata>
      <structure name="JaCoCo Ant Example">
        <classfiles>
          <fileset dir="classes"/>
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
          <fileset dir="src"/>
        </sourcefiles>
      </structure>
      <html destdir="report"/>
    </jacoco:report>
  </target>

  <target name="rebuild" depends="clean,report"/>

</project>
```

If application is executed by some custom homemade tool, then maybe be better to add the agent to the command line directly.

Comment: Hi @Godin I have managed to create the report using the CLI. But for some reason is shows (almost) zero coverage. Can you please checkout my edit to the question?

Comment: "some reason" is IMO clearly stated in warning that you get - "For report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime", i.e. `--classfiles` option for report generation should point on the directory containing exact same class files as were executed.